# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am new in **java Jdbc** I am going to write simple jdbc program `

```
   import java.sql.*;
   class jdbcDemo
     {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","Scott","tiger");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from rk");
    while(rs.next())
    {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"---"+rs.getString(2)+"---"+rs.getInt(3));
    }
    con.close();
    }
 }
```

after Successful compiling program
At runtime i found following error

[image: click here runtime error snapshot]

I had used editplus editor
and also i had created rk table in oracle 12c database

need help to fix issue

Comment: did you add oracle driver to the classpath?

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the class for oracle driver. It will be in a jar which needs to be in class path. Since you are running from command prompt, this needs to be passed to run the class successfully.

Answer (score 0):

As you load class of oracle driver in your code :

**Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");**

you just need to add oracle jdbc drivers(ojdbc6 or ojdbc7 )   into your project . 
you can download this jar file from thislink :
[JDBC DOWNLOAD LINK](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/jdbc-driver-library-download)